# NumberFormatException for input String, confused as to why?

Tags: java, string-parsing

I made a method within a class that is supposed to parse a file with the format: name, xxx-xxx-xxxx
for every line. I'm trying to grab the phone number and put every digit into an array of ints and return that array. Here is my code.

This is the line that causes the error---

```
theIntNumber=Integer.parseInt(justAnotherString);
```

If I had: Nicholas James, 912-345-6789

then....

justAnotherString = "9123456789" and it throws an error when trying to parse that string for an int. I'm confused as to why this is happening, shouldn't it parse the int from this string?

Thank you for any answers.

```
public int[] getPhoneNumberArray() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    while(scan.hasNextLine())
    {
        String thePhoneNumber = "";
        String justAnotherString = "";
        int theIntNumber=0;
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        Scanner parser = new Scanner(line);
        parser.useDelimiter(",");
        parser.next();
        parser.useDelimiter(" ");
        parser.next();
        thePhoneNumber = parser.next();
        Scanner lol = new Scanner(thePhoneNumber);
        lol.useDelimiter("-");
        justAnotherString += lol.next();
        justAnotherString += lol.next();
        justAnotherString += lol.next();
        theIntNumber=Integer.parseInt(justAnotherString);

        for(int i=10;i>0;i--)
        {
            phoneNumberArray[i-1]=theIntNumber%10;
        }
    }
    for(int a=0;a<10;a++)
    {
        System.out.println("Phone Number: ");
    }
    return phoneNumberArray;
}
```

**EDIT**: Previous number was 123-456-7890. The number I had before was larger than the 2.1 billion that java can handle. 987-654-3210 is a better example.

This is the error I'm getting.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9876543210"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at exam2.Contact.getPhoneNumberArray(Contact.java:71)
    at exam2.ExamTwoInput.main(ExamTwoInput.java:83)
```

Comment: Give us the full and exact error message.

Comment: @DennisMeng:  I don't think that it's a dupe, personally.  The question may be similar, but the problem is different.

Comment: @Makoto Yeah, I realized a bit after you that the specific input the author mentioned doesn't actually overflow an int. But had he entered something like 9876543210, then I'd be more inclined to believe it was a dupe.

Comment: Ah. Yeah, now that I see the updated input, I'm more inclined to believe it's a dupe.

Comment: I'm not convinced.  The intended result is completely different than the linked duplicate.

Comment: What specifically about it doesn't strike as a dupe? We've got two questions, both of which tried to parse a phone number with `Integer.parseInt` and got a NumberFormatException.

Comment: I can see that, but the intent is different.  This one seeks to return an array containing every digit in the phone number.  Changing it to a long isn't the best way to go about this, as it doesn't *truly* answer the question.

Comment: This is my first year programming in java or programming in general. I don't have any knowledge of longs or things like that. I'm trying to think of different ways to fix my issue.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be a bad time to learn about longs anyway. But Makoto and Elliott *are* right in that parsing into a int/long isn't the "best" way to do it given that you want to end up with an array with one element for each digit.

Comment: @Makoto Note that the question was about why the `NumberFormatException` occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working here, the only issue I see is that your formula for converting the digits of the `int` number to an array appears flawed. You don't need the `int` anyway, since you have it as `justAnotherString`. Basically, you could use [`Character.digit(char, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit%28char,%20int%29) like -

```
int[] phoneNumberArray = new int[justAnotherString.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < justAnotherString.length(); i++) {
    phoneNumberArray[i] = Character.digit(justAnotherString.charAt(i), 10);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(phoneNumberArray));
```

Of course, you could also parse the telephone number with something like

```
String line = "Nicholas James, 123-456-7890";
// get everything after the last space.
String phone = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
phone = phone.replace("-", ""); // remove the '-' symbols
int[] phoneNumberArray = new int[phone.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < phone.length(); i++) {
    phoneNumberArray[i] = Character.digit(phone.charAt(i), 10);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(phoneNumberArray));
```

which has the advantage that it will work with (and without) dashes.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, you can't store a telephone number in an integer. It loses both leading zeroes, and the plus sign.

For instance, imagine you were given the number for the British Prime Minister, +44 20 7925 0918. The plus sign there indicates that the call is an international call. It would be replaced by 011 in the [North American Numbering Plan,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan) or by 00 in the [European Telephony Numbering Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Telephony_Numbering_Space). How would you represent that telephone number as an int?

Comment: This is a first semester coding class...our professors won't account for international numbers.

Comment: These questions and their answers have a long life. I want to make sure that nobody who reads this in the future gets the impression that it is acceptable to store telephone numbers in integers.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is so old, but till now not have accepted answer.

as your note:

> **EDIT**: Previous number was 123-456-7890. The number I had before was larger than the 2.1 billion that java can handle. 987-654-3210 is a better example.

so, please use `Long.valueOf(str)` instead of `Integer.parseInt(str)` or `Integer.valueOf(str)`

hope this help u all :)